# jQuery doesn't execute on language change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

**UPDATE:**   the problem is that the js is in the UserControl.

I have the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jSonUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Autocomplete/LocalityByPostalCode.ashx") %>';
    var txtPostalCode = '#<%= this.txtPostalCode.ClientID %>';
    var txtLocality = '#<%= this.txtLocality.ClientID %>';

    $(function () {

        var refresh = function () {

            var txtPostalCode = '#<%= this.txtPostalCode.ClientID %>';
            var txtLocality = '#<%= this.txtLocality.ClientID %>';

            //for table row
            onEachPageRefresh(txtPostalCode, txtLocality);

        }

        function onEachPageRefresh(paramPostalCode, paramLocality) {
            $(paramPostalCode).blur(function (ev) {
                var postalCode = $(this).val();
                if (postalCode.length != 4)
                    return;

                $.get(jSonUrl + '?' + postalCode, null, function (responseText, textStatus) {
                    var txtLoc = $(paramLocality).val('');
                    if (responseText.match(/\|/)) {
                        txtLoc.hide();
                        var all = responseText.split('|');
                        var select = $('<select />');
                        for (var i in all) {
                            select.append('<option>' + all[i] + '</option>');
                        }
                        txtLoc.val(all[0]);
                        txtLoc.parent().append(select);
                        select.change(function () { $(paramLocality).val($(this).val()) });
                    } else {
                        txtLoc.parent().find('select').remove();
                        txtLoc.show().val(responseText);
                    }
                }, 'text');
            });
        }

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            refresh();
        });

        refresh();
    });

</script>
```

The problem I have is the following: if I come with English it works. If I switch to Hungarian it doesn't work. The thing is that this script works on other pages of the website. The event doesn't fire. The technology is ASP.NET web forms.

**UPDATE:**

Ok. Here is the update:

I hardcoded the script to the Page, not the UserControl like this

```
 var jSonUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Autocomplete/LocalityByPostalCode.ashx") %>';
        var txtPostalCode = '#MainContent_ucMainBuilding_txtPostalCode';
        var txtLocality = '#MainContent_ucMainBuilding_txtLocality';
```

And it worked. So the problem is that the js is in the UserControl.

Comment: What do you see when you run it in Hungarian - any errors or exceptions? What precisely doesn't work?

Comment: no, I don't see any exceptions, The only thing that happens when I change to hungarian or the page comes loaded with the hungarian language is that it gets other texts from the resources. but that shouldn't interfere with the javascript.

Comment: If I switch to English and then back to Hungarian, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

instead of

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. Although if I switch to English and then back to Hungarian, then it works.

Comment: Try add your `var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    refresh();
});` outside `$(function () {` If i understand, this is what is your problem.